# Ubuntu 18.04 experienced internal error- ubiquity not installed

Tags: system-installation

Downloaded Xubuntu 18.04, checksum agrees, disk check shows no errors but when I try to install I get the internal error message  with details "ExecutablePath usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity Package ubiquity (not installed)". Tried another Ubuntu installation for comparison without any difficulty.